# Making threads redo a print function in order

Tags: c++, multithreading

This is a home assignment.
Have to print a string(given as input) in small chunks(Size given as input) by multiple threads one at a time in order 1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2(number of threads is given as input).
A thread does this printing function on creation and I want it to redo it after all the other threads. I face two problems:
 1. Threads don't print in fixed order(mine gave 1,3,2,4 see output)
 2. Threads need to re print till the entire string is exhausted.

This is what I tried...

```
  #include<iostream>
#include<mutex>
#include<thread>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<condition_variable>
#include<chrono>

using namespace std;
class circularPrint{
    public:
    int pos;
    string message;
    int nCharsPerPrint;
    mutex mu;
    condition_variable cv;
    circularPrint(){
        pos=0;  
    }
    void shared_print(int threadID){
            unique_lock<mutex> locker(mu);
                if(pos+nCharsPerPrint<message.size())
                    cout<<"Thread"<<threadID<<" : "<<message.substr(pos,nCharsPerPrint)<<endl;      
                else if(pos<message.size())
                    cout<<"Thread"<<threadID<<" : "<<message.substr(pos)<<endl;
                pos+=nCharsPerPrint;
    }
};
void f(circularPrint &obj,int threadID){
    obj.shared_print(threadID);
}
int main(){
    circularPrint obj;
    cout<<"\nMessage : ";
    cin>>obj.message;
    cout<<"\nChars : ";
    cin>>obj.nCharsPerPrint;
    int nthreads;
    cout<<"\nThreads : ";
    cin>>nthreads;
    vector<thread> threads;
    for(int count=1;count<=nthreads;++count)
    {
        threads.push_back(thread(f,ref(obj),count));

    }

    for(int count=0;count<nthreads;++count)
    {
        if(threads[count].joinable())
            threads[count].join();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: index starts at `0` in C/C++, not `1`.

Comment: @Jarod42 How can I make thread 1 print again?

Comment: Please add spaces around your `<<` and `>>` operators, it makes the code so much easier to read !

Comment: I says that the loop should look like `for (int count = 0; count != nthreads; ++count) { threads[count].join(); }`

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to multithread a method that can only be executed once at a time?

Anyway, something like this below? Be aware that the `take` and `print` use different locks and that there is a chance the output does not show in the expected order (hence, the why question above).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
class circularPrint
{
public:
    int pos;
    string message;
    int nCharsPerPrint;
    mutex takeLock;
    mutex printLock;
    circularPrint() {
        pos = 0;
    }

    string take(int count) {
        lock_guard<mutex> locker(takeLock);

        count = std::min(count, (int)message.size() - pos);
        string substring = message.substr(pos, count);
        pos += count;
        return substring;
    }

    void print(int threadID, string& message) {
        lock_guard<mutex> locker(printLock);
        cout << "Thread" << threadID << " : " << message << endl;
    }

    void loop(int threadID) {
        string message;

        while((message = take(nCharsPerPrint)).size() > 0) {
            print(threadID, message);
        }
    }
};




void f(circularPrint &obj, int threadID)
{
    obj.loop(threadID);
}
int main()
{
    circularPrint obj;
    //cout << "\nMessage : ";
    //cin >> obj.message;
    //cout << "\nChars : ";
    //cin >> obj.nCharsPerPrint;
    int nthreads;
    //cout << "\nThreads : ";
    //cin >> nthreads;

    nthreads = 4;
    obj.message = "123456789012345";
    obj.nCharsPerPrint = 2;

    vector<thread> threads;
    for (int count = 1; count <= nthreads; ++count)
        threads.push_back(thread(f, ref(obj), count));

    for (int count = 0; count < nthreads; ++count) {
        if (threads[count].joinable())
            threads[count].join();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need inter thread synchronization, each thread doing a loop "print, send a message to next one, wait for a message (from the last thread)".
You can use semaphores, events, messages or something similar.

Something as:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <thread>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

// Parameters passed to a thread.
struct ThreadParameters {
  string message;  // to print.
  volatile bool *exit;  // set when the thread should exit.
  condition_variable* input;  // condition to wait before printing.
  condition_variable* output;  // condition to set after printing.
};

class CircularPrint {
public:
  CircularPrint(int nb_threads) {
    nb_threads_ = nb_threads;
    condition_variables_ = new condition_variable[nb_threads];
    thread_parameters_ = new ThreadParameters[nb_threads];
    threads_ = new thread*[nb_threads];
    exit_ = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < nb_threads; ++i) {
      thread_parameters_[i].message = to_string(i + 1);
      thread_parameters_[i].exit = &exit_;
      // Wait 'your' condition
      thread_parameters_[i].input = &condition_variables_[i];
      // Then set next one (of first one if you are the last).
      thread_parameters_[i].output = 
          &condition_variables_[(i + 1) % nb_threads];
      threads_[i] = new thread(Thread, &thread_parameters_[i]);
    }
    // Start the dance, free the first thread.
    condition_variables_[0].notify_all();
  }

  ~CircularPrint() {
    // Ask threads to exit.
    exit_ = true;
    // Wait for all threads to end.
    for (int i = 0; i < nb_threads_; ++i) {
      threads_[i]->join();
      delete threads_[i];
    }
    delete[] condition_variables_;
    delete[] thread_parameters_;
    delete[] threads_;
  }

  static void Thread(ThreadParameters* params) {
    for (;;) {
      if (*params->exit) {
        return;
      }
      {
        // Wait the mutex. We don't really care, by condition variables
        // need a mutex.
        // Though the mutex will be useful for the real assignement.
        unique_lock<mutex> lock(mutex_);
        // Wait for the input condition variable (frees the mutex before waiting).
        params->input->wait(lock);
      }
      cout << params->message << endl;
      // Free next thread.
      params->output->notify_all();
    }      
  }

 private:
  int nb_threads_;
  condition_variable* condition_variables_;
  ThreadParameters* thread_parameters_;
  thread** threads_;
  bool exit_;
  static mutex mutex_;
};

mutex CircularPrint::mutex_;


int main() {
  CircularPrint printer(10);
  sleep(3);
  return 0;
}
```

using `vector<shared_ptr<...>>` would be more elegant than just arrays, though this works:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -o test test.cc -pthread -Wl,--no-as-needed 
./test
```

Comment: can you please share some links.. Couldn't find them myself.

Comment: I found this and trying to implement, Suggestions? : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/notify_all

Comment: Sounds good, make one condition variable per thread, and pass a couple of cond var to each thread (e.g. input and output).

Comment: Adding a solution in my answer.

Comment: Note that my solution does not directly answer to your assignment, but that should give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Currently each thread exits after printing one message - but you need more messages than threads, so each thread will need to do more than one message.

How about putting an infinite loop around your current locked section, and breaking out when there are no characters left to print?

(You may then find that the first thread does all the work; you can hack that by putting a zero-length sleep outside the locked section, or by making all the threads wait for some single signal to start, or just live with it.)

EDIT: Hadn't properly realised that you wanted to assign work to specific threads (which is normally a really bad idea). But if each thread knows its ID, and how many there are, it can figure out which characters it is supposed to print. Then all it has to do is wait till all the preceding characters have been printed (which it can tell using `pos`), do its work, then repeat until it has no work left to do and exit.

The only tricky bit is waiting for the preceding work to finish. You can do that with a busy wait (bad), a busy wait with a sleep in it (also bad), or a condition variable (better).

Comment: I could, but it's your homework. You'll learn more by figuring it out - honest. (It's doable with one condition variable; more can make it more efficient, but here that is unimportant.)